# git filter-branch: how can I use map function?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm working on a parent-filter and I need to get the (perhaps) *rewritten* revision IDs of the parents of the current revision. I can see on the man-page that there's a *map* function available that can take care of that:

`A map function is available that takes an "original sha1 id" argument and outputs a "rewritten sha1 id" if the commit has been already rewritten, and "original sha1 id" otherwise; the map function can return several ids on separate lines if your commit filter emitted multiple commits.`

However, when I try to use it in my parent-filter script (a bash-based script) the function is not available:

I have this in my code:

```
    echo Finding mapping of revision $i >&2
    map $i >&2
    echo done >&2
```

Result when processing:

```
Finding mapping of revision e73bf9db5c4ce2fb1970c90e3a24a2ff004ec3fe
rewrite_svn_parent.sh: line 44: map: command not found
done
```

Ideally, I would do something like this: `NEW_ID=$( map $i )` but as long as the function is not *available*, can't do much.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

Answer (score 0):

Each of the various filters is run as an `eval` op:

```
parentstr="$(echo "$parentstr" | eval "$filter_parent")" ||
```

(see https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-filter-branch.sh#L389).  This means you have access to shell functions defined in the parent shell.  But in your own script you no longer have them.  This means you must either run everything in this shell, or find some way to export or reproduce filter-branch's `map` (which [isn't really that hard](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-filter-branch.sh#L18-L27) but obviously you're then depending heavily on the implementation).

If this were bash (or if your `/bin/sh` is bash) you could just use:

```
export -f bash; bash /path/to/script
```

as your parent filter, and still write it as a script.  If not, well, the "cheat" method (grab the implementation from filter-branch itself) is probably fine in practice.